# Working With UIViews... Too Much? iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview, interface

Working on an app on which I have a few buttons at the top of the window, Hitting one of these buttons brings up a specific set of UI Elements (such as additional buttons or text fields). I was told during my Google travels searching for an answer, a best way to do this would be using more views, like showing a specific view when Button A was hit, or showing a specific view when Button B was hit. That works greatly, but it worries me. If I wanna have 20 buttons or so, would 20 different views be a problem performance wise? I just feel like thats a lot of views..
Is there a better way to go about this?
Thanks, Joe

Comment: 20 views is not a lot. There are apps out there which regularly use hundreds of UIViews. Don't start optimising too early...

Comment: you can have as many views as you want, but maybe dont have them all loaded in memory at once (aka have them all in the storyboard at the same time), suggestion: create them as separate nibs and load them when they are to be shown, unless that is what you intended in the first place.

Comment: Hmm didn't think of the seperate nibs idea, my issue Is I have a bunch of pretty specific forms. I am going to do that..

Comment: When you guys say 20 Views isn't a lot, your say that intending to load them in as needed, not all starting in 1 storyboard Window correct?

Comment: Truly appreciate all these responses though, this is my first app I am writing I haven't heavily used a tutorial for so its a bit different

Comment: Do you think I should be using container views to pull this off?

Answer (score 1):

In general the views will not be a performance problem.

Also in general don't optimize until you have a test that shows a performance problem. The key to writing good code it to write simple code that is easily understood. Later if there are performance problems investigate, find them and eliminate them. Xcode provides reasonably good tools for this in Instruments.

From [Donald Knuth](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth) Premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of it) in programming.

Comment: Good to know! Thanks, this is the first app I have started to write that I havent been reliant on a tutorial for so its a bit different.

Answer (score 1):

Views are the primary building block for UI in iOS. Having a lot of views is not likely to be a problem.

However, a UI with 20 buttons is likely to be cluttered and hard to use.

Comment: Right, I will have some sort of solution to solving that then. Thanks!